# PHP file_get_contents and exit before page loads

Tags: php, http, file-get-contents

I'm wondering how I can use file_get_contents to load an external page and exit off before the page loads (I don't need the output). Here's the essential flow:

- A: POST request with file_get_contents to B
- B: [`ignore_user_abort(true);`](http://php.net/function.ignore_user_abort) and does a very long action
- A: finishes right after it makes the connection to B
- B: finishes after the very long action

How would I go about "exiting" right when script B starts executing (before the page loads)

Comment: However you do it, you would do the same as if you ask for a single file. So please reduce your question to the needed minimum and then search for it, I have the feeling you'er not the first one asking for it. Right now it's not clear about which part in your question you actually wonder about.

Comment: Ah sorry, the exit before page loads part.

Comment: Okay, I can see my comment was a bit biased, the duplicate question I've reviewed so far here on site are concerned about browser requests. As you do a request with `file_get_contents` the question would be *if* that does as well work with PHP's http wrappers. First of all I would say "Why not?" and then try it out my own if I were you. Example duplicate questions are #138374 and #3270414 but those are actually only two I did review and in the search results I have seen even a few more promising titles.

Comment: I guess as there is no further feedback, it's a somewhat safe bet to choose an early duplicate to hold against until more differentiating and specific information about a new problem arises.

Comment: Yeah sorry about that, I was searching for a duplicate for a while before posting this and couldn't find one. That's it though, thanks.

Comment: well if that fully answers your question, I'm lucky I could point it to you then. If this does not work with `file_get_contents` please leave a comment and edit the question a little to make clear what the differences to the duplicate are.